# Is the sequence $s_j = \sum_{k=0}^{k=j}e^{ik^2}$ bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, limits, complex-numbers

Let

$$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{ik^2}$$

where $i$ is the imaginary number. Is the sequence $s_n$ bounded in the complex plane ?

I have considered expanding the function $e^{z}$ at $z = ik^2$ which is in fact

$$e^{ik^{2}} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{i^{j}k^{2j}}{j!}}$$

so that

\begin{align} 
s_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {\frac{i^{j}k^{2j}}{j!}} \\ 
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {\frac{i^jp_{2j}(n)}{j!}} 
\end{align}

where $p_{2j}(x) = 0^{2j}+1^{2j}+... +x^{2j}$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: You are asking a question about what is known as a *theta function*. I suggest you search on that term, and report back to us on what you find.

Comment: I would suspect that this sequence is bounded. Here is a heuristic explanation that can probably be rigorized. Note that $e^{ik^2}$ is a complex number with angle $k^2$ modulo $2\pi$. To study how $k^2$ behaves mod $2\pi$ we can equivalently look at $k^2/2\pi$ mod $1$. Now it is known that this sequence is equidistributed (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) so one would suspect that all the 'diifferent' angles would appear and hence $s_n$ should be close to $0$.

Comment: See [THIS](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201250/is-sum-k-1n-sink2-bounded-by-a-constant-m).  The magnitude of the sum is NOT bounded.